# How to execute EF5 savechanges from a derived BindingNavigator class

Tags: entity-framework-5, dbcontext, savechanges, bindingnavigator

I've created a cutom BindingNavigator with custom ToolStripButton(s), basically working with datasets, in which I've coded delegate actions to perform when adding, deleting and updating records.
As I'm moving to EF5, I would like to make the same thing, the idea still the same, but when executing these three methods:

```
this.BindingSource.AddNew();
this.BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
this.BindingSource.Update();
```

modifications are made in runtime but not in database.

I found later that i must execute
    context.SaveChanges();

to make data concrete.

Can anyone help on how to call the context from the custom binding navigator class.